# Using a Bluetooth module without MCU

Tags: adc, arm, bluetooth-low-energy, st-link

I am making an EEG using an [ADS1299](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299.pdf).

To read the data I want to use a Bluetooth module and send data to a PC (I think [this one](https://br.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Dialog-Semiconductor/DA14531MOD-00F01002?qs=vmHwEFxEFR%2FOK5Vt%252Bf%2FdqA%3D%3D) should be OK) and power both with 2 coin cell batteries.

Can I do this using only the embedded ARM microcontroller of the Bluetooth module using SPI?

Can I program it using a ST-LINK v2? Do you guys know any writen guide for Bluetooth modules? The datasheet is very confusing on how to use it.

Comment: I am working on the similar project but instead of using nrf52840 module, I am planning to use Seeed XAIO nrf52840 sense board. I have been looking for similar projects and I found your post. Would you like to exchange some note?

Answer (score 0):

There are several Bluetooth modules that you may consider. These days choosing one that is available and in stock may be more what decides the use of a module. In your case if data is the only thing you require, ensure that it is at least Bluetooth BLE or more (due to some recent 2021 changes to the certification requirements that render previous < Bluetooth 4.0 modules not recommended for new designs - this depending also on the region).
In your case what you'd need to master mostly, whether you require BLE or not, is understanding and making use of RFCOMM to set-up data pipes for your communication to a PC (or to any other peripheral or host etc). The datasheet should have a list of Bluetooth classic and BLE commands to be used for serial comms... good luck !